# Unable to locate package mitmf

Tags: linux, installation

I am trying to download mitmf for kali linux i am following the steps on youtube videos.
But when i get step to the step:

```
sudo apt-get install mitmf
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mitmf
```

Why is there ocurring and is there a work around?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this is the most simplest solution.

> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

Add these lines in the end of the file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali-rolling/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali-rolling/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then add the key:

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6

Then run

> sudo apt-get update

Now you should have most of the packages that is present in Kali linux, mitmf is one of them.

> sudo apt-get install mitmf

Comment: still showing "Unable to locate package mitmf"

Comment: Repeated lines, and not working

Answer (score 0):

**Solved Unable to Locate Package**

1. Enter the command: leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Remove everything within that sources.list file
3. Google for "Kali Linux Repository"
4. Scroll down and look for "The kali-rolling repository"
5. Copy everything within that kali-rolling and paste on sources.list file
6. Save the sources.list file
7. Run the command: apt-get update
8. Now install ur package(e.g:apt-get install mitmf)

Answer (score 0):

1. Type `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` and hit enter
2. Remove all the repositories listed in the file.
3. Open the official website https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/ and enter the required repositories in the file and save the file.
4. Now run  `sudo apt update && apt full-upgrade` and Hit enter.
5. Finally enter `sudo apt-get install mitmf` and hit enter.

Comment: what all are required?